# Change a line thickness using d3.select

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, c3.js

I currently am working on a basic chart using c3.js API.

I want to change the thickness of one of my lines **without changing my CSS file**.

I cannot figure out how to do a proper d3.select to change it's **thickness**.

So far I tried for my line `data2` : `d3.select("c3-line-data2").attr("stroke-width",50);` but it ain't work.

Comment: Given the minimal information you provided, you are probably missing a single dot in you selector string to select the line having that **class**: `d3.select(".c3-line-data2")`. The way you have it would try to select the element of **type** `c3-line-data2` which makes no sense in this context.

Comment: On top of what @altocumulus said, `attr` won't work here, you have to use `syle`. This is an example, look at the last line: https://jsfiddle.net/acuuh2nq/

Comment: The `.` and `style` instead of `attr` made it! Thank you :)